# Errors when creating remote projects using Eclipse Remote System Explorer

Tags: android, eclipse, ide

I have never used the Eclipse Remote System Explorer until today so perhaps this is obvious. I primarily use my lubuntu 12.10 desktop for development but I decided it would be convenient to set up Remote System Explorer so I could work on projects using my Windows XP laptop when I happen to be away. I installed the RSE components, set up the ssh connection and I am able to log into the linux box and access and import all of my files. However, when I used the "Create Remote Projects" option to import a simple Android Hello World application I got an error:

> This project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.

However, there is a project.properties file in the project and I am not sure what I should change, if anything, or if I am using RSE incorrectly.

Update: I did try right-clicking on the project -> Android Tools -> Fix project properties

but this did not do anything and the error still appears.

Answer (score 0):

One advice : just forget about the Remote System explorer. It's already enough painful to make Eclipse correctly aware of a local folder.

Second advice, if it's not a constraint for you, start use IntelliJIdea, it will change you dev working days and save you a lot of time.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, but I am really just looking to get this problem solved. I have used Eclipse quite a few project and have never had a problem with it. Maybe someday I will look at a different IDE but not right now if I can help it.